# Pine Script - Change timeframe of chart programmatically

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Please let me know, is there any way to change the charts's time frame programmatically using Pine Script?

[image]

i.e., change 5min time frame to 15min time frame using Pine Script? When I add my indicator, chart should load with 15mins candles.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to change the chart's timeframe via pinescript.

You can, however, request data from other timeframes using the [security](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html) function. You can also use the `timeframe.multiplier` and `timeframe.period` to figure out chart's timeframe, and select the timeframe you want to use with the `security()` according to that.